# Disable window on Mac OS

Tags: c++, macos, qt, cocoa, user-interface

How to disable window on Mac OS from Qt application in order it can't be moved? I didn't find any good cross-platform way so trying to do it separately for Windows using  `EnableWindow` and it works. What is the way for Mac OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as we didn't find good cross-platform way to do this, we ended with separate code for Windows and Mac OS. Here is the code we used for Mac OS to enable / disable window:

```
#include <AppKit/NSView.h>
#include <AppKit/NSWindow.h>

void MacOSUtils::enableWindow(WId id, bool enable)
{
    NSView * view = reinterpret_cast<NSView*>(id);
    Q_ASSERT(view);
    NSWindow * window = [view window];
    [window setMovable:enable];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is not a cross-platform way to prevent the window from moving. But you can override  `QWidget::moveEvent` like :

```
void MyWindow::moveEvent(QMoveEvent *event)
{

    if (event->pos() != QPoint(100,100))
          move(QPoint(100,100));

}
```

This does not update until mouse is released.

Another approach is to set `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` flag for window and render your custom titlebar.